# hIcon ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: c++, winapi

I am developing a C++ application which has a notifyIcon which is updated dynamically. Things have been going great, except for this ONE problem; the hIcon becomes NULL, and throws ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED. I can't for the life of me work out what's happening. Here's my code where I draw the HICON:

```
// hIco is initialised like this:
// hIco = CreateIcon(NULL, 32, 32, 1, 32, { 0x00 }, { 0x00 });
//HICON hIco;
void CreateGraphIco() {
int width = 32;
int height = 32;
const int size = 32 * 32 * 4;

// Get old icon buffer
ICONINFO info = { 0 };
GetIconInfo(hIco, &info);
BYTE xorBuffer[size];
BYTE andBuffer[size];
GetBitmapBits(info.hbmColor, size, xorBuffer);
GetBitmapBits(info.hbmMask, size, andBuffer);

// (The drawing code for the icon is quite long,
// complicated, and irrelevant, so i'll leave it out)

hIco = CreateIcon(NULL, width, height, 1, 32, andBuffer, xorBuffer);

DeleteObject(info.hbmColor);
DeleteObject(info.hbmMask);

notify.hIcon = hIco;
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, &notify);
}
```

---

While this does work, it only works for a couple of seconds, or minutes until eventually, the notifyIcon will disappear and hIco will become NULL.

---

Any help would be appreciated! I'm really struggling with this issue, and I would be very thankful if someone could help me resolve this. I'm sure I've made some stupid mistake which I haven't even noticed.

---

Cheers!

Comment: `notify.hIcon = hIco;` And if there was an old icon? Have you called `DestroyIcon` on it? Looks pretty much like a memory leak... Unfortunately, [API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648059%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is not precise about anything, but I could imagine `CreateIcon` allowing to create only a limited number of icons or use only a limited amount of mermory. `ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED` - I assume you got it via `GetLastError`?

Comment: Yeah, I got 'ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED' from 'GetLastError'. You think I should call 'DestroyIcon' _before_ calling 'CreateIcon'? I'll give that a try, originally I had 'DestroyIcon' after my main while loop.

Comment: You don't call `GetLastError`. If you want help, we'll need a [mcve].

Comment: Alright, DestroyIcon seems to have fixed it. Thank you @Aconcagua! David, i'll be sure to read that link you sent me next time I post a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so basically for anyone having this same issue in future, make sure you call `DestroyIcon` before calling `CreateIcon`. 

Thanks Aconcagua!